# Can I use the same userpool to enable social login(google) in Amazon AWS cognito?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

It is possible to use the same userpool to enable amazon (aws) cognito userpool to enable social login- google authentication, or I need to create new userpool to enable google authentication? And if I need facebook should i create another userpool? Becouse i wont going to have password if i decide to use the existing userpool? Is it a problem or not if I can use the existing userpool or I need to create a new userpool to enable google authentication? Thanks for your help!

I was read a lot articles about this but its confusing for me, should I create a new userpool or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new Userpool, you can use your existing Userpool and add new federated identity providers to it.

The existing userpool has to meet some requirements (which they do by default) such as the mapped attributes (to relate the fields from the provider to the cognito user fields) needing to be mutable. Find more information about it on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html).

After [configuring the social identity provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html), you should [link the provider user to the (native) Cognito user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation-consolidate-users.html), so that they are recognized as the same user and the token claims are common if logged via username/password or via identity provider.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to implement in asp .net core and angular that i wont going to have a password? Becouse I need password to login in my old code but I didnt find any good tutorial how to implemenet google federated identity in c#. I think I need to use tokens to signup and signin but I didnt find any good tutorial for this.